# null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint but id already serialized and the request goes through to the database?

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

to elaborate on the title I'm working on a database in postgresql with the backend written in symfony/php, I am encountring a persistent error:

> An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
> DETAIL: Failing row contains (null, O:36:"Symfony\Component\Messenger\Envelope":2:{s:44:"\0Sym..., [], default, 2022-06-01 09:03:24, 2022-06-01 09:03:24, null).

but the Id is already serialized afaik:

```
 /**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
 * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="client_id_seq", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1) 
 */
private $id;
```

Weirder still, the request (in this case a new user signup) actually goes through to the database and I can see the email and password on dbeaver.

Comment: Okay, what is your question? You are saying database throws error and the application goes through the database. So, either there is a missing relationship in the architecture of application or you are looking wrong direction. What is id, what is the e - mail? It is your architecture. You should give more details.

Comment: You're right, my bad! the error is thrown by symfony after I fill in the sign up form. The email is part of the architecture of the user table (id, email, role, password, is_verified).

Comment: @UmutTEKİN So my question is where is this coming from and would it be a problem in the future? is there a way to side step it?

Comment: What do you see when you check your table? There should not be any null values, but there is? One of the reason could be that when you sign up the form, it triggers a different event that cause this problem and then your actual sign up process runs and completes successfully.  Maybe, your sign up process tries to fill another table?

Comment: According to this information there should not be problem, because application is running :). Yet, absence of evidence is not evidence of absence :). Hovewer, you have error messages :S. You should debug it.

Comment: @UmutTEKİN In retrospect I should have thought of this way sooner "it triggers a different event that cause this problem and then your actual sign up process runs and completes successfully. " , the problem was with my email verification controller which was being called on every registration but I forgot about it, thanks!